# Animation: jelly doesn't work

Tags: css

I've tried to create a button that animates to the left, and then back ti the right again, to it's normal state. Animation doesn't work with this code:

```
.fortnite-wrapper .btn.btn-display:after {
content: "";
display: block;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 2em;
background-color: #ff0;
-webkit-transition: background-color .3s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: background-color .3s ease-in-out;
 transition: background-color .3s ease-in-out; 
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 4px 12px -4px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
 box-shadow: 0 4px 12px -4px rgba(0,0,0,.5); 
 -webkit-animation: jelly 6s ease-in-out infinite; 
animation: jelly 6s ease-in-out infinite;
-webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50% 20px;
-ms-transform-origin: 50% 50% 20px;
transform-origin: 50% 50% 20px;
}
```

Left side of the button should expand to the left for 20 px and then go back, animation is infinite.
HTML for button:

```
<div class="fortnite-wrapper">
<button class="btn download-button btn-primary btn-display play-free"> 
<span>Fortnite</span></button>
</div>
```

Comment: What about the HTML? And the Keyframes for the CSS animation `jelly` you use in this code?

Comment: Here is an html for button

     `<div class="fortnite-wrapper">
  <button class="btn download-button btn-primary btn-display play-free"> 
        <span data-reactid="204">Fortnite</span></button>
       </div>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, you didn't define the animation `jelly`, which is needed to tell the element which properties to animate.

Secondly, `animation-direction: alternate` makes the animation reverse itself after completion. This is neccessary in order to keep the element from jumping back to the start. In this snippet I put it into `animation: jelly 2s ease-in-out infinite alternate;`.

```css
.fortnite-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
}

.fortnite-wrapper .btn.btn-display:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2em;
  background-color: #ff0;
  -webkit-transition: background-color .3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: background-color .3s ease-in-out;
  transition: background-color .3s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 4px 12px -4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  box-shadow: 0 4px 12px -4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  -webkit-animation: jelly 2s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
  animation: jelly 2s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50% 20px;
  -ms-transform-origin: 50% 50% 20px;
  transform-origin: 50% 50% 20px;
}

@keyframes jelly {
  0 {
    width: 100%;
  }
  100% {
    width: calc(100% - 20px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="fortnite-wrapper">
  <button class="btn download-button btn-primary btn-display play-free"> 
<span>Fortnite</span></button>
</div>
```

Edit: In order for the animation to only affect the left side of the block without changing the rest of it, I recommend animating the property `width` instead. If you use it in combination with `position: absolute` and `right: 0` the element will in- and decrease in size on the left side.

Comment: Thanks a lot, and how can I apply this animation to the left side of the yellow block only? So the right side would stay on it's place?

Comment: Great! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.outer {
  margin: 50px;
}

.button {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 3px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  display: block;

  background: linear-gradient(to right, black 50%, white 50%);
  background-size: 200% 100%;
  background-position: right bottom;
  transition: all .5s ease-out;
}

.button:hover {
  background-position: left bottom;
}

.text {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 30px; 
  color: black;
  transition: all .6s ease-out;
  display: block;
}

.text:hover {
  color: white;  
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="button">
    <div class="text">button</div>
  </div>
</div>
```